# PHP Invalid argument supplied for foreach() loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make sure every column in a database will pull from an HTML but only the first two columns will pull.  The last three columns don't work.  Two are text values and the last column is a decimal.  Can someone please tell me what I am missing?  Thank you!

```
$colmName = $_POST["colName"];
   $colmValue = $_POST["colValue"];
   $count = 0;

   if ($colmName = 'productID')
    {
      $theQuery = "SELECT * FROM products
                   WHERE productID = $colmValue";
      $rSet = $db->query ($theQuery);
    }
    elseif ($colmName = 'categoryID')
     {
      $theQuery = "SELECT * FROM products
                   WHERE categoryID = $colmValue";
      $rSet = $db->query($theQuery);
     }
    elseif ($colmName = 'productCode')
     {
      $theQuery = "SELECT * FROM products
                   WHERE (productCode = '$colmValue')";
      $rSet= $db->query($theQuery);
     }
    elseif ($colName = 'productName')
   {
      $theQuery = "SELECT * FROM products
                   WHERE (productName = '$colmValue')";
      $rSet = $db->query ($theQuery);
     }
    elseif ($colName = 'listPrice')
     {
       $theQuer = "SELECT * FROM products
                   WHERE listPrice = $colmValue";
       $rSet = $db->query ($theQuery);
     }
    else
     {
       echo ('Enter a valid column name from the products table and an existing value.  Either productID, categoryID, productCode, productName, or listPrice.');
       include (index.html);
       exit ();
     }//end if

   foreach($rSet AS $products)
    {
      $list .= $count.' '.$products['productID']
                     .' '.$products['categoryID']
                     .' '.$products['productCode']
                     .' '.$products['productName']
                     .' '.$products['listPrice']
                     .'<br>';
      $count++;
    }//foreach

    echo ("<p>The data for $colmName with a value of $colmValue is listed below:<p>");
//    echo ($list);//just to check if it works before putting it in a table
//    echo ('<p>');//for spacing
?>


<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Product Results</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <section>
                        <table border="1">
                                <tr><th>productID</th><th>categoryID</th><th>productCode</th><th>productName</th><th>listPrice</th></tr>
                                <tr><td><?php echo $products['productID'];?></td><td><?php echo $products['categoryID'];?></td><td><?php echo $products['productCode'];$
                        </table>
                </section>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of php are you running? `foreach` can only be used on query results in >= 5.4 versions.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Yes I'm using the most recent version for now (for learning purposes).  Thank you everyone for the suggestions.  Actually the issue was the "=" versus "==".  Apparently PHP does not consider it conditional even thought it is an "if" condition to begin with.  So I had to change it to == and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the `$db->query` is just a regular mysql_query() function, you cannot use foreach.  You should use:

```
while ($products = mysql_fetch_assoc($rSet)) {
    $list .= $count.' '.$products['productID']
                 .' '.$products['categoryID']
                 .' '.$products['productCode']
                 .' '.$products['productName']
                 .' '.$products['listPrice']
                 .'<br>';
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
foreach($rSet AS $products)
```

With

```
while ($products = mysql_fetch_assoc($rSet))
```

Not enterly sure that db-library you are using. It does not look like ext/mysql.

If you are using PDO, the line should be

```
while ($products = $rSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```